# JFrame and MIDI not working when together

Tags: java, swing, midi

So basically, I'm trying to make a basic synthesizer in java, just as a fun side-project. It has two parts at the moment, both of which work fine on their own, but not together. The first part sets up the synthesizer and plays a note. The second part sets up a JFrame. This is sourcefile:

```
import javax.sound.midi.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*; 
public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { 
        try { 
            Synthesizer synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer(); 
            synth.open(); 

            MidiChannel[] channels = synth.getChannels(); 

            channels[0].noteOn(60, 60); 
            Thread.sleep(200); 
            channels[0].noteOff(60); 

            synth.close(); 
            System.out.println("Did the sound stuff."); 


            JPanel pane = new JPanel();             
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sound1"); 
            JButton button1 = new JButton("Click me!"); 
            System.out.println("Things added."); 
            pane.add(button1); 
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
            frame.add(pane); 
            System.out.println("Pane added."); 
            frame.setSize(300,200); 
            frame.setVisible(true); 
            System.out.println("frame is visible now."); 

            button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
                   System.out.println("Clicked!"); 
               } 
            }); 
        } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) { 
            System.out.println(e); 
            System.exit(1); 
        }    
    }  

}
```

It will get to the "Did the sound stuff" statement, and then the program will stop responding, without drawing the window. Any idea what could be causing this? Again, the JFrame related stuff compiles fine without the sound stuff.

Comment: Your code works fine for me, but you could be blocking the EDT.  You should make sure that the UI is also created within the context of the EDT, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details